# Return all possible combinations of values within a single column in SQL

Tags: sql

How do I return a list of all possible combinations of values from within the same single column of database 'x'? For example I have:

```
    col 1,
    1
    2
    3
    4
```

And I would like to return a list of all possible combinations like,

```
    1,2
    1,3
    1,4
    2,3,
    2,4
    3,4
```

....

Comment: Are all of your values distinct?  Could you ever have `a=1,b=1,c=2` and want to return {`a=1,b=1`,  `a=1,c=2`,  `b=1,c=2`}?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You've not said which RDBMS you are using or whether you want to limit the combinations to just 2 elements of the set.

Here is an Oracle answer using hierarchical queries:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/09bdd/8)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST ( COL ) AS
SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 5;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(COL, ','), 2) AS combination
FROM TEST
CONNECT BY PRIOR COL < COL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/09bdd/8/0)**:

```
| COMBINATION |
|-------------|
|           1 |
|         1,2 |
|       1,2,3 |
|     1,2,3,4 |
|       1,2,4 |
|         1,3 |
|       1,3,4 |
|         1,4 |
|           2 |
|         2,3 |
|       2,3,4 |
|         2,4 |
|           3 |
|         3,4 |
|           4 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(COL, ','), 2) AS combination
FROM   TEST
WHERE  LEVEL = 2
CONNECT BY PRIOR COL < COL AND LEVEL <= 2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/09bdd/8/1)**:

```
| COMBINATION |
|-------------|
|         1,2 |
|         1,3 |
|         1,4 |
|         2,3 |
|         2,4 |
|         3,4 |
```

And an SQL Server version using a recursive CTE:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/98acf/10)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST ( COL INT );

INSERT INTO TEST
          SELECT 1
UNION ALL SELECT 2
UNION ALL SELECT 3
UNION ALL SELECT 4;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH cte ( combination, curr ) AS (
  SELECT CAST( t.COL AS VARCHAR(80) ),
         t.COL
  FROM   TEST t
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CAST( c.combination + ',' + CAST( t.col AS VARCHAR(1) ) AS VARCHAR(80) ),
         t.COL
  FROM   TEST t
         INNER JOIN
         cte c
         ON ( c.curr < t.COL )
)
SELECT combination FROM cte
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/98acf/10/0)**:

```
| combination |
|-------------|
|           1 |
|           2 |
|           3 |
|           4 |
|         3,4 |
|         2,3 |
|         2,4 |
|       2,3,4 |
|         1,2 |
|         1,3 |
|         1,4 |
|       1,3,4 |
|       1,2,3 |
|       1,2,4 |
|     1,2,3,4 |
```

Answer (score 10):

```
select concat(t1.id, ",", t2.id) from t t1 join t t2 on t1.id < t2.id;
```

An SQL Fiddle example can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81ad4/57).

```
concat(t1.id, ",", t2.id)
-------------------------
1,2
1,3
1,4
2,4
2,3
3,4
```

Comment: Great answer, simple and effective, just a point, based on the criteria the condition of the join can be changed to t1.id <> t2.id

Comment: @MohsenSichani - No, `<>` would allow both `1,2` and `2,1`, thus yielding permutations rather than combinations.