# How to generate unique combinations of 1-3 values from same column? (Order MOSTLY doesn't matter)

Tags: sql, oracle, combinations

I have a column of ice cream flavors. I am trying to generate all possible combinations of 1-3 scoops of ice cream. The flavors can repeat.

Order doesn't matter, **except** when it comes to null values. Scoop 1 can never be null, and scoop 2 can't be null if there is a scoop 3.

I have tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Scoop1.Flavor, Scoop2.Flavor, Scoop3.Flavor
FROM icecream Scoop1, icecream Scoop2, icecream Scoop3
```

- The problem with the above is that it generates "rotated" combinations where rows will have the same combination of 3 scoops, just in different orders. So 'chocolate, strawberry, vanilla' should be treated the same as 'strawberry, vanilla, chocolate' and 'vanilla, chocolate, strawberry', and so on.

And also tried:

```
SELECT A.Flavor, B.Flavor, C.Flavor
FROM icecream A, icecream B, icecream C
WHERE A.Flavor != B.Flavor
AND A.Flavor != C.Flavor
AND B.Flavor != C.Flavor
```

- The problem with this one is that it doesn't output any combinations containing more than one of the same flavor (which was not a surprise, I was just trying to stop the rotation from the first example to cut down the results a bit).

** Both have the problem that there are no combinations with only 1 or 2 scoops, it always generates combinations of 3 scoops.

---

Am I even **remotely** on the right track...? This is for a homework assignment, and I've been working on it for several hours and now my brain is mush.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a where clause to eliminate different orderings and combine different scoop numbers with unions

```
SELECT Scoop1.Flavor, '<empty>', '<empty>'
FROM icecream Scoop1
UNION ALL
SELECT Scoop1.Flavor, Scoop2.Flavor, '<empty>'
FROM icecream Scoop1, icecream Scoop2
WHERE
    Scoop1.Flavor >= Scoop2.Flavor
UNION ALL
SELECT Scoop1.Flavor, Scoop2.Flavor, Scoop3.Flavor
FROM icecream Scoop1, icecream Scoop2, icecream Scoop3
WHERE
    Scoop1.Flavor >= Scoop2.Flavor AND Scoop2.Flavor >= Scoop3.Flavor
```

Answer (score 1):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

The basic idea is:

```
SELECT ic1.Flavor, ic2.Flavor, ic3.Flavor
FROM icecream ic1 CROSS JOIN
     icecream ic2 CROSS JOIN
     icecream ic3;
```

However, this doesn't provide `NULL` scoops.  For that, you need to introduce a new row:

```
WITH ic as (
      SELECT flavor
      FROM icecream
      UNION ALL
      SELECT NULL
     )
SELECT ic1.Flavor, ic2.Flavor, ic3.Flavor
FROM icecream ic1 CROSS JOIN
     icecream ic2 CROSS JOIN
     icecream ic3
WHERE ic1.Flavor IS NOT NULL AND
      NOT (ic2.Flavor IS NOT NULL AND ic3.Flavor IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

**update 1**

As a second glance I must say that I didn’t notice the unique constraint. The below query outputs “rotated” combinations.

**end update 1**

**update 2**

I think you should see into generating unique combinations with recursive cte’s.
This is what I found on that topic: [Return all possible combinations of values within a single column in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31070337/return-all-possible-combinations-of-values-within-a-single-column-in-sql)

**end update 2**

Simple cross joins with the where clause

```
with t as (
 select 1 as f
 union all select 2
 union all select null
 union all select 4
 )

 select distinct
  t.f,
  t1.f,
  t2.f
 from t
 cross join t t1
 cross join t t2
 where t1.f is not null
 order by t.f, t1.f, t2.f asc
```

**Schema (PostgreSQL v10.0)

```
| f   | f   | f   |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1   | 1   | 1   |
| 1   | 1   | 2   |
| 1   | 1   | 4   |
| 1   | 1   |     |
| 1   | 2   | 1   |
| 1   | 2   | 2   |
| 1   | 2   | 4   |
| 1   | 2   |     |
| 1   | 4   | 1   |
| 1   | 4   | 2   |
| 1   | 4   | 4   |
| 1   | 4   |     |
| 2   | 1   | 1   |
| 2   | 1   | 2   |
| 2   | 1   | 4   |
| 2   | 1   |     |
| 2   | 2   | 1   |
| 2   | 2   | 2   |
| 2   | 2   | 4   |
| 2   | 2   |     |
| 2   | 4   | 1   |
| 2   | 4   | 2   |
| 2   | 4   | 4   |
| 2   | 4   |     |
| 4   | 1   | 1   |
| 4   | 1   | 2   |
| 4   | 1   | 4   |
| 4   | 1   |     |
| 4   | 2   | 1   |
| 4   | 2   | 2   |
| 4   | 2   | 4   |
| 4   | 2   |     |
| 4   | 4   | 1   |
| 4   | 4   | 2   |
| 4   | 4   | 4   |
| 4   | 4   |     |
|     | 1   | 1   |
|     | 1   | 2   |
|     | 1   | 4   |
|     | 1   |     |
|     | 2   | 1   |
|     | 2   | 2   |
|     | 2   | 4   |
|     | 2   |     |
|     | 4   | 1   |
|     | 4   | 2   |
|     | 4   | 4   |
|     | 4   |     |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hEDDqCf8EBH7RWvxNxYwh2/0#)

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down the problem.

Start with two scoops. It does simplify things if you add a row with a NULL flavor:

```
with flavors(flavor) as (
select 'vanilla' from dual union all
select 'strawberry' from dual union all
select 'chocolate' from dual union all
select null from dual
)
select * from flavors a
join flavors b on a.flavor <= nvl(b.flavor, a.flavor)

FLAVOR       FLAVOR
chocolate    - 
chocolate   chocolate
chocolate   strawberry
chocolate   vanilla
strawberry   - 
strawberry  strawberry
strawberry  vanilla
vanilla     - 
vanilla     vanilla
```

This works because of the way Oracle handles NULL in comparisons! When you compare NULL to anything, even another NULL, the result is "unknown". Even when you compare NULL to itself, the result is never "true". Bottom line: this condition ensures that a.flavor will not be NULL, which is what you want.

Now all we have to do is add the third scoop:

```
with flavors(flavor) as (
select 'vanilla' from dual union all
select 'strawberry' from dual union all
select 'chocolate' from dual union all
select null from dual
)
select * from flavors a
join flavors b on a.flavor <= nvl(b.flavor, a.flavor)
left join flavors c on b.flavor <= nvl(c.flavor, b.flavor);
```

The left join ensures that we keep the rows where there was only one scoop to begin with.