# Return all possible combinations of values within a single column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL. How do I return all possible combination from a single column and count total corresponding column. For example:

```
name   | grade
-------------------
john   | A
any    | B
cindy  | C
kim    | C
```

Will return something like this:

```
mark   | count
-------------------
A      | 1
B      | 1
C      | 2
AB     | 2
AC     | 3
BC     | 3
ABC    | 4
```

I've looking for a solution, the closest one is this [Return all possible combinations of values within a single column in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31070337/return-all-possible-combinations-of-values-within-a-single-column-in-sql). But in only generate combination and in ORACLE.

Here is the data set that I created for this question:

```
CREATE TABLE users
    (`name` varchar(5), `grade` varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO users
    (`name`, `grade`)
VALUES
    ('john', 'A'),
    ('any', 'B'),
    ('cindy', 'C'),
    ('kim', 'C')
;
```

...and SQL fiddle of same:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36924d/1

Comment: May be I don't understand the question, but the answer should be a simple `GROUP BY` e `count(*)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use recursive common table expression:

```
with recursive cte (n) AS
(
  select distinct cast(u.grade as char(255)) from users u
  union all
  select concat(u.grade, c.n) 
  from users u
    join cte c on u.grade != c.n
  where position(u.grade in c.n)=0
    and u.grade < c.n
)
select c.n, count(*) 
from cte c
  join users u on position(u.grade in c.n)
group by c.n
```

See [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b0ecfba6808368b5a760f385dd90fb33)

Comment: Wow, quite complex. Can you explain this a bit ?

Comment: It works like a charm, but can you explain what this query does sir?

Comment: Changed to dbfiddle.uk which does not have collation problems like db-fiddle making the query simpler. The recursive CTE builds all the combinations of strings by starting from the distinct values and in each recursive round adds a string to the result set if it it not already there while keeping the alphabetical order. The actual query does a simple join with aggregate function to find out occurances of each substring from all possible combinations.