# All possible combinations of data in a single table in alphabetical order

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a simple SQL query to show all possible combinations of data in a single table. Here's the table:

| id | fruit |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apple |
| 2 | orange |
| 3 | pear |
| 4 | plum |

I've only got as fair as *pairing* all the data using CROSS JOIN: "apple,orange", "apple,pear" etc.

```
SELECT t1.fruit, t2.fruit
FROM fruits t1
CROSS JOIN fruits t2
WHERE t1.fruit < t2.fruit
```

Instead I'm looking for all unique combinations in alphabetical order, e.g.

- apple
- apple,orange
- apple,orange,pear
- apple,orange,pear,plum
- apple,pear
- apple,plum
- apple,orange,plum
- apple,pear,plum
- orange
- orange,pear
- orange,pear,plum
- orange,plum
- pear
- pear,plum
- plum

i.e. as long as a combination exists once, it doesn't need to appear again in a different order, e.g. with `apple,orange`, there is no need for `orange,apple`

Comment: "i.e. as long as a combination exists once, it doesn't need to appear again in a different order" - That's what we call combinations usually. Permutations are when you want them to appear in a different order again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for any table size.
[Result here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wWDpb2MbFQtWVBYQKfx3B7/1)

Note: this requires MySQL 8+.

```
-- TABLE

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fruits`
(
    `id`     int(6) NOT NULL,
    `fruit`  char(20)

);
INSERT INTO `fruits` VALUES (1, 'apple');
INSERT INTO `fruits` VALUES (2, 'orange');
INSERT INTO `fruits` VALUES (3, 'pear');
INSERT INTO `fruits` VALUES (4 ,'plum');



-- QUERY

WITH RECURSIVE cte ( combination, curr ) AS (
    SELECT
        CAST(t.fruit AS CHAR(80)),
        t.id
    FROM
        fruits t

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        CONCAT(c.combination, ', ', CAST( t.fruit AS CHAR(100))),
        t.id
    FROM
        fruits t
    INNER JOIN
        cte c
        ON (c.curr < t.id)
)
SELECT combination FROM cte;
```

**Credit:**
Code adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31070585/2983568)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: This query doesn't give all the possible combinations.**

Below query should work:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT A.id,
        CONCAT(A.fruit,',',GROUP_CONCAT(B.fruit ORDER BY B.id)) AS combinations,
        COUNT(*) AS count_of_delims 
    FROM fruits A 
    INNER JOIN fruits B 
    ON A.id<B.id 
    GROUP BY A.id,A.fruit
  
    UNION ALL
  
    SELECT id,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(combinations,',',count_of_delims),
        count_of_delims-1 
    FROM cte 
    WHERE count_of_delims>0
)
SELECT combinations FROM cte ORDER BY id;
```

Here is a [working example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2E1c7Ctzw8sFG8nqFRSWxq/0) in DB Fiddle.